# linux shell $? is not 0 after scp command when the shell is exec in tow fork process, Why?

Tags: python, bash, shell, scp

shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
scp -q /local/opt/file_test remote_host:~/ 2>&1
echo $?
exit 0
```

python code:

```py
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import signal
import sys
from multiprocessing import set_start_method

def _detach_with_context(executor):
   # 放在context外面, 减少开销
   os.setsid()

   signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN)

   pid = os.fork()
   if pid > 0:
       sys.exit(0)

   try:
       if pid < 0:
           sys.exit(0)

       # 执行任务
       executor()
   except Exception as ex:
       pass
   finally:
       sys.exit(0)


def detach_autosql_execute(executor):
   try:
       p = Process(target=_detach_with_context, args=(executor,))

       p.start()
       p.join()
   except Exception as ex:
       executor.failure(f'create daemon process error: {ex}')


def execute():
   command='sh ./test.sh'

   p = subprocess.Popen(
       command.encode('utf-8'),
       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
       stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
       shell=True,
       encoding='UTF-8'
   )
   print(''.join(p.stdout.readlines()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
   set_start_method('spawn')
   detach_autosql_execute(execute)
```

The local host and the remote host 'remote_host' are ssh password-less login.
The 'echo $?' normal is 0, but the shell script echo $? is 1,
When I exec the shell script only by command, the echo $? is 0
When I exec the shell script in one fork process, the echo $? is 0
But when i exec the shell script in two fork process, the echo $? is 1

Why?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Which error are you getting when `scp` fails? Which version of the script produces which result?

Comment: I am not sure, but, as 1 fork process runs OK, and fails for 2, I think when you exec two process, the second process finds the resources are locked by the first process.

Comment: If you're trying to understand why `scp` says there's a problem, then why are you specifying `-q` (quiet mode)? That seems counterproductive to me . . .

Answer (score 0):

You use in your script  `~/` to denote your home directory, but this is a bash feature. However you run your script using `sh ./test.sh`, which means it is executed by POSIX shell. I suggest that you invoke your script by `bash ./test.sh` or specify your home directory in the script by `$HOME` instead of `~`.

**UPDATE**: Why it still is not a good idea to run a script which is (based on its #! line) intended for bash, using `sh`, your usage of tilde expansion should not cause any difference, as @tripleee pointed out in their comments.

Comment: [`~` is in fact in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01), though it's of course possible that the OP's `sh` is pre-POSIX.

Comment: Anyway, using it in an `scp` target means it is evaluated by `scp` (try `echo foo:~/bar` and observe that the shell does not perform any expansion).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. i should have checked this. Being grown up with old Bourne shell, I was not aware that POSIX has blessed ~ too.

Comment: Note that you can delete your answer if you no longer believe it to be correct.

Comment: @ruakh : I am aware, but I wonder whether it is not too early for this. While certainly my explanation is wrong, the only oddity with the problem the OP has, is, that he is running a bash script with sh.Maybe he did not post the complete script? Also, I think deleting the answer would also make the comments to the wrong answer inaccessible; but at least the comments by tripleee are valuable, and should not go away.